# Prove that if $A$ is finite, then $A \cup \{b\}$ is finite. Where $b \in B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble proving this:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets where $A \subseteq B$. Let $b \in B$. Prove that if $A$ is finite, then $A \cup \{b\}$ is finite.

So what I know is that since $A$ is finite, then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A\sim J_n=\{1,2,3\ldots,n\}$

Also if $A$ is finite and $B \subset A$, then $B$ is finite.

Im just having trouble seeing where to go from here and if I need to use both of these definitions. Also this $A \cup \{b\}$ is throwing me off.

Comment: If you have a bijection $\sigma$ from $A$ to $J_n$ and $b\notin A$, can you construct a bijection from $A\cup\{b\}$ to $J_{n+1}$ (using $\sigma$)?

Comment: Forget about the $A \sim J_n$ thing for now. Do you know what a finite set is? Can you give an example of a finite set?

Comment: @ThePortakal Without wanting to look condescending, that "$J_n$ thing" is kind of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set#Definition_and_terminology) of a finite set.

Comment: B doesn't matter.  It can be finite, infinite, a subset, a superset, disjoint.  Whatever.  Anything but empty.  You aren't unionize with B but with a single element of b.  You are adding *one* element to A.  Is a still finite.  (Actually the are two cases: $b\not \in A $ in which case you are adding one element.  And $b\not\in A $ in which case do you know what is happening?)

Comment: Are you in a Set Theory/Logic class? This will determine the amount of rigor needed in your answer.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by $J_n=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$? Are you saying that $J_n$ is infinite?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo sorry I meant $J_n$ is a finite set.

Comment: @yoyostein yes i am lol

Comment: Please write down precisely what $J_n$ is. Obviously it is not what you wrote.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for all the input. I am just having trouble seeing the bijection from $A \cup$ {b} to $J_{n+1}$. How do I declare one.

Comment: You start from the one that is "promised" to you from $A$ to $J_n$, and then you "add" $b \mapsto n+1$ to it. (This is, again, assuming $b\notin A$).

Comment: Formally: you have f:{1,....,n}-- > A.  f is a bijection.  Define g:{1....,n+1}-- > A U {b} as g (i) = f (i) if i <= n.  g (i) = b if i = n+1.  That is clearly a bijection.

Answer (score 3):

$A \cup \{b\} $ just means you are adding one more element to $A $.

But $A\subseteq B $ so we need to be careful.

Case 1: $b\in A $.  Then $A \cup \{b\}=A $.  Which is finite.

Case 2: $b \not \in A $.

$A $ is finite so we have a mapping from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $A$.  Simply extend that map and map $n+1\rightarrow b $.  Now we have a 1-1 mapping from $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$ to $A \cup \{b\} $.

So it is finite.

Comment: thanks! I knew it involved cases since adding $b$ to $A$ could just be adding a new number or something already in $A$. Anyways im not sure what you mean with "mapping  $a_i ==i$ " and map " $i == a_i$ , or map $n+1==b$

Comment: All the numbers 1,...,n are mapped to .members of A.  So just map n+1 to b.  You're done.

Answer (score 0):

For finite sets you can just note that if $A$ has $n$ elements, then $A\cup\{b\}$ has either $n$ or $n+1$ elements, depending on whether $b$ is in $A$ or not.

If you really want to use bijection (which is quite unnecessary in this case), you may construct a bijection to a set of order $n$ or $n+1$, either case it is still finite.

Comment: The whole point seems to be to prove that using the very definitions, as far as I can tell. I.e., "how do you define that a set is finite"? "How do you formally define the cardinality of a finite set"? Here, you just take that for granted and wing it.

Comment: Reacting to your edit after my comment: *no*, it's not "unnecessary." If you learn things by building them from the axioms (as quite a few courses do), you *need* to deal with that at some point. It is necessary, unless you want to have intuitive but shaky foundations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the point of the exercise is to precisely to get the student used to bijection and to understand even something as intuitive as "A has n elements" needs a formal definition.